# Q: Headfirst Java for-loop exercise (Mixed Messages CH5)

Tags: java, for-loop, output

I have been struggling with an exercise in the Java Headfirst book( CH5: p121 for reference). It's a loop inside another loop which adds/substracts some values from instance variables.

**Input**:
x = x + 3

**Outputs**:
x= 54      y = 6

```
public class MixFor5 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 30;
  for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {
   for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
    x = x + 3;
    y = y - 2;
    if (x == 6) {
     break;
    }
    x = x + 3;
   }
   y = y - 2;
  }
  System.out.println(x + " " + y);
 }
}
```

My result is when doing it by myself with a notepad is **x=42 y = 8** because then both loop conditions are met. What am i doing wrong? where did I go wrong in my thoughtprocess?

these are my notes -> [pastebin note](http://pastebin.com/K2tb4Uqd)

I have not tried debugging first because I want to figure this by myself  first so that I don't make the same mistakes in the future.

Thanks in advance,

tvanderv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(x == 6)` will never get true. The reason behind this is,

When `inner = 4`

`x = x + 3` executes two times i.e. means `x = 6`.

then, `inner = 3`
now first `x = x + 3` (before `if(x == 3)` condition) will give output `x = 9`. So `x > 6` it will not break loop.

You did this step wrong in your notes.